# Write file to absolute path outside of app directory [Node.js]

Tags: node.js, fs, absolute-path, writefile, enoent

I'm trying to create and write to a file in a folder outside of node app's source folder.

I have a absolute path like this `E:\myFolder\`
but when I try to `writeFile` with `fs` it throws `ENOENT` error.

I've created `E:\myFolder` manually, but I think the problem is my app can't see outside of it's own folder.

Any way to solve this?

Comment: Writing files is not limited to the app folder, but you need to make sure that you escape the paths properly (`fs.writeFile('E:\\myFolder\\myFile.txt', ...)`). Backslashes have a special meaning in JS scripts.

Comment: I've escaped it, but now I came upon conclusion that problem is because in filename there are some illegal characters like ":". What is a standard way to remove all illegal characters from filename string?

Comment: There isn't really a standard way, but there are [various packages](https://npms.io/search?q=clean+filename) that can help you.

Comment: Thanks. If you want, you can make your comments a answer so I can accept it.